# URL id equals to if statement or elseif statement to open page

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

### 1- Work correct in this step

[image: this url work]

This is correct work
[image]

### 2- Work not in this step

help me in this step

index.blade.php page

navbar code

```
 <nav class="navigation">
          <ul class="sf-menu">
            <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('about') }}">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Category</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="{{ url('grid/1') }}">Buy and Sell</a></li>
                <li><a href="agent-detail.html">Car and Vehicles</a></li>
                <li><a href="my-properties.html">Real Estate</a></li>
                <li><a href="submit.html">Pets</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricing.html">Jobs</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.html">Community</a></li>
                <li><a href="404.html">Resumes</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
```

1. problem in this anchor tag (1) pass to URL
   [image]

My Route code

```
Route::resource('/', 'BasicController');
Route::resource('about', 'BasicController@about');
Route::resource('contact', 'BasicController@contact');
Route::resource('grid', 'BasicController@grid');
```

This is my controller code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BasicController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){  
        return view('index');
    }
    public function about(){   
       return view('about');
    }

    public function contact(){
       return view('contact');
    }
     public function grid($id)
{  
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    if ($id == 1) {
       return view('buy-and-sell/grid');
    }
    elseif ($id == 2) {
        return view('car-and-vehicels/grid');
    }
    elseif ($id == 3) {
        return view('country/grid');
    }
    else{
         return view('other/grid');
    }

  }
}
```

click on buy and sell 
[image]

### To Face this problem

1. First problem
   [image]

   ### BasicController

   public function grid($id)
   {

   ```
   $id = $this->uri->segment(3); <!-- Line number 30-->

   if ($id == 1) {
      return view('buy-and-sell/grid');
   }
   elseif ($id == 2) {
      return view('car-and-vehicels/grid');
   }
   elseif ($id == 3) {
      return view('country/grid');
   }
   else{
      return view('other/grid');
   }
   ```

   }
2. second problem
   [image]

Comment: Too many pictures, not enough code.

Comment: I have upvoted you from -1. People here are sometimes very rude, if they do not understand a problem at once or it's not their prefferred way of thinking. You have put a lot of effort into describing your problem, alone this does not deserve a -1. althoug only having screenshots is uncommon;-) but in the end it contained everything to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the following changes:

1.) Your method signature is wrong. See below, Laravel will pass in the "number" automatically from your url in the variable $id (but as second(!) argument). Be ware you also have to import the Request in the header via an `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` statement!

```
public function grid(Request $request, $id)
```

2.) Dont use `$this->uri->segment` but rather use the passed $id directly (this is the slug that represents segement 3). You are using resource Controllers and Laravel does the mapping automatically for you.

So it should look likes this:

```
public function grid(Request $request, $id)
    {  
        //$id = $this->uri->segment(3); //COMMENT THIS OUT!!!

        if ($id == 1) {
           return view('buy-and-sell/grid');
        }
        elseif ($id == 2) {
            return view('car-and-vehicels/grid');
        }
        elseif ($id == 3) {
            return view('country/grid');
        }
        else{
             return view('other/grid');
        }
```

3.) Regarding the CSS. You got your paths wrong, but this is extremely hard to debug/help without further information

Important: Its seems you are running laravel as a subfolder install. You will run into very strange problems (like this one, I suspecte this the subfolder install could be the reason). I have opened a bug at laravel some time ago, but it got closed. Subfolder Installs are not supported.

I really advise you to install laravel as described on their homepage as a dedicated virtual host, that the `public` folder maps to the domain itself (like http://localhost) in other words "public" is your root folder that is served directly under http:://localhost.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment. The CSS stuff is easily fixable. See my (updated) notes above. I first advise you to install laravel as a dedicated host (otherwise it is much more complex and I ran into problems myself (also with urls) that I was not able to fix. So I also switched from subfolder install to the "dedicated virtual host" install. If you have done this, it should be easy to fix, you only have to have a look at the CSS URLS why they fail. Use Chrome Developer Tooolbar for this.

Comment: check step one on top the question that is correct work -> but pass id in url to create this problem